# Understanding how file-pages work at the technical level

Tags: c++, database

I am working on a file-page manager program and have to code the following function:

```
RC readPage(PageNum pageNum, void *data)
This method reads the page into the memory block pointed to by data. The page should exist.
readPageCount = readPageCount + 1;
return 0;
}
```

so basically and object of type filehandler will be passed to a function of the file manager class  which basically creates, opens, destroy files. This file handler provides functionality such as reading and writing records to a specific page in the file.

I don't understand how this works at the technical level. How do we create a page within a file?. I understand what the concept of page is but how does that translate to an actual physical page in a file?. In the project it was specified that the page size is 4096 bytes.

I understand how the record formats work, but just at the abstract level. I know this may be a long answer, so if you are reluctant to provide an answer, providing a good source explaining this topic would be great. I am having troubles finding the right resources to understand this topic.

Answer (score 0):

At the level of code you're writing, **you** decide how file pages work. There is no magic involved here.

Note that there is no "actual physical page in a file". A file system is a logical abstraction. The closest physical thing we might have is a block storage device such as a harddisk. And that may not have have 4096 byte blocks; 512 byte blocks are also common. CDs have yet another block size (2KB?).